# Completely stuck trying to get a value from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been trying to figure out how to get the value of 'text' in this array using PHP and after many attempts, I've not got to the stage of giving up.

Can somebody tell me how to get the translated text in 'text' from this array? It's returned from using the REST API on Microsoft Azure Translator Service and is a JSON object according to documentation, but no matter what I try I can't get any of the text from any part of the array using code. A pointer would be very much appreciated before I lose what hair I have left!

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [detectedLanguage] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [language] => en
                    [score] => 1
                )
            [translations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => Entrez votre texte ici
                            [to] => fr
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 5):

Objects are accessed by arrows `->` and arrays are accessed by square brackets `[]` in PHP.

You can see each is labelled as `stdClass Object` or `Array`. So work down the response as so:

```
$response[0]->translations[0]->text
```

To break it down...

#### `$response[0]`

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [detectedLanguage] => stdClass Object
            (
                [language] => en
                [score] => 1
            )
        [translations] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [text] => Entrez votre texte ici
                        [to] => fr
                    )
            )
    )
```

#### `$response[0]->translations`

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [text] => Entrez votre texte ici
                        [to] => fr
                    )
            )
```

#### `$response[0]->translations[0]`

```
                stdClass Object
                    (
                        [text] => Entrez votre texte ici
                        [to] => fr
                    )
```

#### `$response[0]->translations[0]->text`

```
                Entrez votre texte ici
```

I hope that weird example helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wasn't managing to figure out - after a long day of going around in circles!